# iCloud synchronization does not work for an app on iPhone 4S and 5

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

**Summary:**

Application installed on iOS (iPhone 4S or iPhone 5 - tested on both) that supports iCloud synchronization does actually not synchronize with iCloud. The iOS version is 6.1.2.

We are developing an application and added iCloud support. The provisioning profile was recreated with iCloud enabled and stored on the device. The entitlements were properly configured in xcode to use iCloud and a Key-Value Storage (the values for the identifier are set to defaults). We followed the Apple's iCloud Design Guide tutorial to implement functionality to sync with iCloud (using the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore class to store and read values).

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Use an app with iCloud support (in development mode or an app installed from the App Store) on iPhone 4S or 5 (iOS 6.1.2 installed). Go to Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data and have Documents & Data enabled and Use Cellular Data disabled. Try to use the application with iCloud. The data are not synced between devices. We also tried as follows: run the application, store a value to iCloud, delete the application, install the application again, run the app, the value could not be retrived from the iCloud.

Turn off the iPhone and turn it back on.
Go to Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data and enable Use Cellular Data.

Now run the application with iCloud enabled and the value stored in the iCloud. The value is synced from the iCloud ... everything is working as it should.

**Expected Results:**

The iCloud synchronization works if Use Cellular Data is disabled and Document & Data is enabled in Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data.

**Actual Results:**

The iCloud synchronization will not work if Use Cellular Data is disabled in Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data.

**Notes:**

Also the notification NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification has never fired the selector set unles the Use Cellular Data was enabled in Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data.

Could anyone reproduce the same behavior?
Could someone make iCloud sync to work with Use Cellular Data disabled in Settings > iCloud > Documents & Data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reproduced: I am an app user with a wifi-only iPad 3 and an iPhone 4S. I had Cellular Data enabled, but not for iCloud Documents. Key-Value synching did not work until I enabled for Cellular Data for iCloud Documents.

Answer (score 1):

**iCloud Key Value Storage** is not reliable as it is expressed in [iCloud Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH7-SW1).

Data propagation might be delayed because of Key Value Storage throttling.

From the "**Preferences and Settings**" guide:

*"The key-value store is intended for storing data that changes infrequently. If the apps on a device make frequent changes to the key-value store, the system may defer the synchronization of some changes in order to minimize the number of round trips to the server. The more frequently apps make changes, the more likely it is that later changes will be deferred and not show up on other devices right away."*

Sometimes, due to this KVS throttling, `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` doesn't fire, even if both **Documents & Data** option and **Use Cellular Data** option are enabled.

This might be your issue.

If not, you should wait for Apple staff to reply your bug report. (I suppose you have reported a bug, as your question is in Apple Bug Report format.)

Comment: I tried to make iCloud sync working in our app for days and it just didn't work. The "store did change" notification was never fired. When I saved a value through the class NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore, reinstalled the app, I never got the value back. Same behavior on two mentioned iPhones. As soon as I enabled Use Cellular Data, the syncronization started to work. I wasn't waiting for more than just a few seconds. I tried several times the mentioned process and it worked each time. As soon as I disabled Use Cellular Data, nothing worked again. You are right, I reported this as a bug.

Comment: Then It really looks like a bug, if you can reproduce this problem everytime you swith on and off Use Cellular Data option. Could you please let me know what Apple staff replied to your bug report?

Comment: Yes, I realy can reproduce it everytime. I will let you know instantly when/if I get the answer from Apple. So far no luck.

Comment: OK, I'm waiting. Thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe try to reproduce this?

Comment: Apple responded. They asked me to send the logs so they can investigate on the described behavior. I'll let you know as soon as I get more info. Please let me know if you tried described steps and if you encountered the same behavior.

Comment: I tried but not managed to reproduce it. When it doesn't sync, switching Use Cellular Data option on and off has no effect. It persistently doesn't sync. And when it starts syncing again, it syncs even if Use Cellular Data option is off. But, I'll try it again tomorrow with another device and iCloud account.

Comment: I had not much time lately. I replied to Apple yesterday. Did you try it with the other device and iCloud account?

Comment: When iCloud sync stops working on iPhone 4S and 5 I need to turn the device off, turn it back on and switch Use Cellular Data again on (or let it just be enabled if it already was before I turned the device off). I realy can reproduce this every time.